# Obtain the value that occurs the maximum number of times in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

```
Tuple            Expected
(0 , 0, 1)         0
(-1, 0, -1)       -1
(0, -1, 1)         0            
(0, 1, 1)          1
```

If no value found return zero.

Comment: Have you tried writing one? What happened?

Comment: Use the `collections.Counter` function to count the values. Sort them by the count and return the first item.

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter` among other things

Comment: @Barmar Instead of sorting. I think we can use `max` with `key` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You use this.

```
from collections import Counter
a=(-1,0,-1)
b=Counter(a) #Counter({-1: 2, 0: 1})
out=max(b,key=lambda x:b[x]) #-1
```

If you want count with it use this.

```
out=max(b.items,key=lambda x:x[1])#(-1,2) it means -1 occured 2 times which is max.
```

All of this can be incorporated into one-line.

```
max(Counter(a).items(),key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count element occurrences in tuples.

`collections.Counter` returns a dictionary where the keys are the elements of the tuple and the values are the occurrences of those elements.

```py
from collections import Counter

def elem_max(tup):
    # count the element occurances
    count_dict = Counter(tup)

    # check if different value occurs the same time
    for key, val in count_dict.items():
        for key1, val1 in count_dict.items():
            if key != key1 and val == val1:
                return 0

    # check if each value occurs only once
    if len(set(count_dict.values())) <= 1:
        return 0

    else:
        # sort the dict keys by values in ascending order
        # and select the keys with max value
        count_max = sorted(count_dict, key=(lambda key: count_dict[key]))[-1]

        return count_max
```

Use the function like this

```py
a = (1, 0, -1)
b = (1, 1, 0)
print(elem_max(a))
print(elem_max(b))
```

This should show :

```
>> 0
>> 1
```

This even works for cases where two elements can occur the same amount of time. The function returns zero in that case.

```py
c = (1, 1, 0, 0, 2)
```

This returns,

```py
>> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit: @Redowan Delowar and @Ch3steR

```
from collections import Counter

def elem_max(tup):

    b= Counter(tup)

    out=max(b.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])

    if(out[1] ==1):
      return 0 
    else:
      return out[0]
```

**Test case**

```
tup1 = (1,-1,1)
tup2 =  (1, 0, -1)
print(elem_max(tup1)) # 1
print(elem_max(tup2)) # 0
```

Comment: Problem is, this fails when the tuple has elements that occur the same amount of times. Like `(-1, 0, -1, 0)`. Ideally, this should print 0. In my opinion, to remove ambiguity, when there are no matches, the function should return `False` instead of 0.

Comment: Thanks for creds, and sorting takes `O(nlogn)` whereas `max` takes `O(n)`. Not saying answer with sorting is bad but using `max` is more efficient here.

Comment: With more elements in the tuple e.g 4, the result would fail new test case e.g. 
a =(-1, 0, 1, -1).